# Flutter root Column widget expanding to whole screen, why?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm new to flutter / dart and am just finding my feet.

Been having a play with a really simple test UI.  I'm using the Material App and Scaffold widgets and placing a Column widget in the 'body' of the Scaffold widget.  It automatically expands to take up the whole screen when I use the inspect widget tool.

This is the code..

```
class TestWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text('bob'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If I then nest a Column widget it doesn't expand to take up the vertical space like its parent did, I can change that and take up the space by using the Expanded widget like this..

```
class TestWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Text('bob'),
          Expanded(
            child: Column(children: [
              Text('bob2'),
            ]),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm just trying to understand why the parent 'root' Column takes up all the space it can by default but when I remove the Expanded widget the nested Column doesn't?

Must be something simple but I'm not seeing it when I look through the docs and understand.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a layout constraint applied to the root widget by Flutter.

Comment: Ahhh thank you, I've not looked into constraint's yet so my knowledge is limited.  Will look through them in the docs and try and understand a little more :)